# How to get the ID of a specific gist revision?

Tags: github, revision, gist

I try to use the following link template to reference different revisions of a gist:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<gist-id>/raw/<revision-id>/<filename>
```

but I can only get the latest `<revision-id>` when accessing the 'raw' version of the file.

How to get the `<revision-id>` of an arbitrary revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you use should work. Make sure you replace `<revision-id>` with the correct commit hash. In the GitHub UI, go to **Revisions**, find the proper one, on the file under **...** click **View file**, and then the **Raw** button.